# siri shortcuts handle timeout

Tags: post, timeout, shortcut, siri

I have a siri shortcut which sent data via URL post to an php file.
This works fine.

Problem is: If I have no internet connection at this moment, I will get a time out and the whole siri shortcut will be cancel with a time out message.

Is there a way to handle this time out like "try again" or something else?

Comment: I am having this same issue. After hours of searching I still couldn't find anything relevant. Did you manage to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Get current IP address" action and an "If" action:

https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/156f48da9b284ebd81cf6c43bfa252ae